# Remix - How to get parent action data in child route?

Tags: javascript, remix.run

Is it possible to retrieve the data acquired in the parent action without having to refetch them?

For example:
`routes/parent.tsx`
`routes/parent.$id.tsx`

In the `parent.tsx`, in action route, I get some data:

```
export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request }) => {
    const data = something
    return data;
}
```

How to get these same data in the child route `parent.$id.tsx` without having to refetch them in the loader route ?

Answer (score 0):

The useOutletContext hook is what you are looking for.

Details are in the docs: https://remix.run/docs/en/main/hooks/use-outlet-context

Comment: Please expand your answer with an explanation instead of only linking to the documentation.